# Cannot resolve github dependency even though my process is correct

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, jitpack

Basically the problem is I cannot resolve GitHub dependency even though I added this to Project level build.gradle.

`build.gradle` (Project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and app level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:country-picker-android:<latest-version>'
```

How can I fix this? What is this cause possibly? I already updated to the lastest version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string `implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:country-picker-android:<latest-version>'` at the app level build.gradle file you must replace `<latest-version>` substring with the actual version of the library. Currently the latest version is 2.0.1.

So the result string should be this: `implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:country-picker-android:2.0.1'`